# Renaming files in folder using shell script

Tags: perl, shell, video, rename

I have downloaded a playlist of videos and want to organise them using a file called android playlist. For eg: the first file with some title like "Introduction to Android.mp4" , I have to rename it as 1.mp4 . I don't know perl or unix but I have managed to write this code so far:

```
`IFS=''
c=0
d=0
e=1
while read line
 do
     d=`expr $c % 4`
     if [ $d == 0 ]
     then
     echo $line
     rename -n `s/${line}.mp4/${e}.mp4/` *.mp4
     e=`expr $e + 1`
     fi
     c=`expr $c + 1`
done < Android\ playlist`
```

but this is giving error:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd"
    (Missing operator before rd?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd Party "
LocationEntry Solution - Developing Android Apps
ren.sh: line 11: s/LocationEntry Solution - Developing Android Apps.mp4$/243.mp4/: No such file or directory
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd"
    (Missing operator before rd?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd Party "
SQLiteOpenHelper onUpgrade() method - Developing Android Apps
ren.sh: line 11: s/SQLiteOpenHelper onUpgrade() method - Developing Android Apps.mp4$/244.mp4/: No such file or directory
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd"
    (Missing operator before rd?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd Party "
JUnit testing - Developing Android Apps
ren.sh: line 11: s/JUnit testing - Developing Android Apps.mp4$/245.mp4/: No such file or directory
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd"
    (Missing operator before rd?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd Party "
InsertReadDbTest - Developing Android Apps
ren.sh: line 11: s/InsertReadDbTest - Developing Android Apps.mp4$/246.mp4/: No such file or directory
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd"
    (Missing operator before rd?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd Party "
InsertReadDbTest Solution - Developing Android Apps
ren.sh: line 11: s/InsertReadDbTest Solution - Developing Android Apps.mp4$/247.mp4/: No such file or directory
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd"
    (Missing operator before rd?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "3rd Party "
Simplify Tests - Developing Android Apps
ren.sh: line 11: s/Simplify Tests - Developing Android Apps.mp4$/248.mp4/: No such file or directory
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Try to use double-quote, not backtick for this: `rename -n "s/${line}.mp4/${e}.mp4/" *.mp4`

Comment: Why has the question a perl tag?

Comment: because rename uses perl expression and double quotes is not working!

Comment: @tivn, That only solves one of the three or four problems with that line.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, Because `rename` is written in Perl, the argument is supposed to be Perl code, and the OP is having problem determine what to pass as the argument.

Comment: @ikegami I also thought mv is the one should be used. My previous suggestion is to 'reduce' the error message.

Comment: The correct modification was rename "s/${line}............\.mp4/${e}.mp4/" *.mp4 . Sorry my fault though. Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: No, that still has numerous problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rename -n `s/${line}.mp4/${e}.mp4/` *.mp4
```

should be

```
mv "${line}.mp4" "${e}.mp4"
```

Comment: This is giving Error: mv: cannot stat ‘Update Map Intent - Solution - Developing Android Apps.mp4’: No such file or directory
Lesson 6 Recap - Developing Android Apps
mv: cannot stat ‘Lesson 6 Recap - Developing Android Apps.mp4’: No such file or directory
Storytime: Future of Android - Developing Android Apps
mv: cannot stat ‘Storytime: Future of Android - Developing Android Apps.mp4’: No such file or directory
Congratulations! Android Party! - Developing Android Apps
mv: cannot stat ‘Congratulations! Android Party! - Developing Android Apps.mp4’: No such file or directory

Comment: That's because you are telling it to rename files that don't exist.

Comment: These files are in the folder. I am trying to rename these file from a file called Android playlist. I am reading the Android playlist, finding the file and then renaming as 1.mp4 then I move to the next line and rename the next file as 2.mp4 .. This is what I am trying to do. The script and the files are contained in same folder.

Comment: `mv` disagrees. I'll take its word over yours. Doesn't matter what directory the script is in; you said to look in the current work directory.

Comment: the files contained some extra characters which I hadn't noticed. Thanks